# Does sample variance has a Chi-square distribution?

Tags: distributions, variance, sample, chi-squared-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ be a random sample from $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Does
$S^2=\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(X_i-\bar X)^2}{n-1}$ has a Chi-square distribution?

I know that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}=\frac{\sum^n_{i=1}(X_i-\bar X)^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2(n-1)$

But how do we know if $S^2$ also have a Chi-square distribution or not?
Thank you

Comment: Since the $\chi^2$ distribution is not closed by a change of scale, multiplying a $\chi^2$  variate by $\sigma^2/n-1$ returns a not-$\chi^2$ variate.

Comment: Put another way, if $\frac{(n-1)S^s}{\sigma^2}\sim\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = n-1).$ then $S^2$ does not have a chi-squared distribution unless $\sigma^2=(n-1).$ Otherwise, you might say $S^2$ has a _multiple_ of a chi-squared distribution.